# Autofill Read-Host input with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm having a hard time to trying to auto-fill the `Read-Host` input in PowerShell

I have a script that reads files, extracts lines and store them in a CSV file for fruther changes.

I'd like to be able to change each line on demand from the Powershell window without having to re-type the entire line.

1. Read the file
2. Find the next available line
3. Make the line the `Read-Host` input
4. User would then use the arrow keys to move the cursor and make changes to the line
5. Press Enter to save the line to a new file

"_" in the below example of the desired state of `Read-Host` is the cursor blinking ready to makechanges*

```
#> Line to change : server=servername.loc.corporation_
```

Answer (score 3):

If you add `[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("YourText")` before `Read-Host` this should help you. But it work only if console window has focus.

Comment: I don't even remember asking that

Comment: It was for my previous company, we can dump this thread

Comment: @JeanneD4RK on the contrary: SE sites are for problems that are general enough to be helpful in the future. This answer is actually *exactly* what you wanted to do and what I wanted to do in 2019.

Comment: If you use this, you will probably need to add `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms` to the top of your script.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic approach to get you started. You should really be including the code you're trying and specific examples of where you're getting stuck.

The below will output one line at a time, then ask the user to input whatever they want. This input can be a replication of the original line, or any changes they wish to make.

```
$sourcefile = gc "file1.txt"
$newfile = "file2.txt"

foreach ($line in $sourcefile) {
     Read-Host "Edit this line -" $line | Out-File -Append $newfile
}
```

Comment: So people will still have to **rewrite the whole line** instead of **editing pre-filled** ? That's my only problem, the rest of the script works well.

Comment: If this doesn't help you get started, then post your code and tell exactly where you're having problems.